# PHP/MySQL: Get name for specific ID

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner to MySQL and Im trying to retrieve a name for a specific ID.

Here is how my database looks like:

I have a table of contacts which contains ID, first and last name.

I want to retrieve the first and last name for a specific ID in the same form.

So I want to end up with a form of options and the option value will be the first name for each ID.

For example:

```
<form>
<select name="users">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="5"> <?php echo "$first $last" ?> </option>
<option value="10"> <?php echo "$first $last" ?> </option>
<option value="15"> <?php echo "$first $last" ?> </option>
</select>
</form>
```

The values are the ID's.

and my PHP:

```
<?php   include("connection.php");

$query="SELECT * FROM contacts";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$first=mysql_result($result,$i,"first");
$last=mysql_result($result,$i,"last");

$i++;
}

?>
```

in my actual example I get the first and last name of the last's person in the database only.

So how can I retrieve the first and last name for specific ID's of which I assign in my form (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your while loop is overwriting $first and $last every single time. Try

```
$users = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
  $users[] = $row;
}
```

And in HTML (EDITED):

```
<form>
  <select name="users">
    <option value="">Select a person:</option>
    <?php foreach($users as $row): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['first'] . " " .  $row['last']; ?> </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't compile: <?php echo "$row['first'] $row['last']" ?>. I tried this: echo $row['first']; echo $row['last'] and it works but there is not space between first name and last name

Comment: Sorry I didn't check syntax. I edited the HTML portion so that it adds a space between first and last name.

Comment: Thank you. This works as printing all the ID's. What If I want to print first and last name for ID 13 and 15 only? That was my question.

Comment: If you know which ID you want at the time of querying, then you can change your sql query to "SELECT * FROM contacts where id in (13, 15)" If not, then you can add a if statement in the HTML portion. <?php if($row['id'] == 13 || $row['id'] == 15): ?>/* ... */<?php endif; ?> Sorry for the code in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your contacts table has a primary key field, you'd use THAT field to put into your `<option>` tags as the value. Then you've got a 1:1 correspondence between a particular `<option>` and a record in the database. If you go by name alone, you'll end up (say) 5 "John Smith" entries and it would be impossible to tell which one you want.

So, make your query be:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname
FROM ...
```

and then:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       echo <<<EOL
<option value="$row[id]">$row[firstname] $row[lastname]</option>

EOL;
    }
```

Comment: According to your paragraph, you are right and that is my question. I want to have my primary key of which is the ID, in the option's value and then print the name for that specific ID. But your answer doesn't seem to compile in PHP. Note that I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = $_POST['users'];
$query = 
"SELECT 
    ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME 
FROM 
    CONTACTS 
WHERE 
    ID = '$users'";
```

Of course, while this works, it is a classic example of a SQL injection vulnerability.  You'll want to either sanitize the input or use a prepared statement and binding variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

`$query="SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = '$id'";`

A little googling will go a long way. Read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) and [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html).

Comment: I am aware of that but this gives you only the first and last name for 1 id.